# Windows CMD. How do I corectly use two inner loops in FOR cycle?

Tags: css, batch-file, cmd

Code below enumerate network cards and output info in html file

```
rem | Write SCC

@ECHO ^<head^>^<style^> >> %~dp0%computername%.html
@ECHO .div-main {width: 100%%; height: 800px; padding: 10px; margin: 10px;} >> %~dp0%computername%.html
@ECHO .div-table {display: inline-block; width: auto; height: 790px; border-left: 1px solid black; padding: 10px; float: left; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;} >> %~dp0%computername%.html
@ECHO .div-table-sec {display: inline-block; width: auto; height: 790px; border-left: 1px solid black; padding: 10px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;} >> %~dp0%computername%.html
@ECHO .div-table-row {display: table-row;} >> %~dp0%computername%.html
@ECHO .div-table-cell {width: auto; padding: 10px 50px 10px; border-top: 1px solid black; border-left: 1px solid black; float: left;} >> %~dp0%computername%.html
@ECHO .div-table-cell-zero {width: auto; padding: 10px 50px 10px; border-top: 1px solid black; border-left: 1px solid black; float: left; color: red;} >> %~dp0%computername%.html
@ECHO .div-table-cell-sec {width: 256px; padding: 10px 50px 10px; border-top: 1px solid black; border-left: 1px solid black; float: left;} >> %~dp0%computername%.html
@ECHO .div-table-cell-third {width: 128px; padding: 10px 50px 10px; border-top: 1px solid black; border-left: 1px solid black; float: left;} >> %~dp0%computername%.html
@ECHO ^</head^>^</style^> >> %~dp0%computername%.html

rem | Open Main DIV
@ECHO ^<div class=^"div-main^"^> >> %~dp0%computername%.html

rem | Open table DIV
@ECHO ^<div class=^"div-table^"^> >> %~dp0%computername%.html

rem | Gather info on connections
rem | Get Connection name and its mac address
@FOR /F "skip=2 delims=, tokens=2,3" %%i IN ('wmic nic where PhysicalAdapter^=true get MACAddress^, NetConnectionID /format:csv') DO (

rem | Write Connection name as table row, as header of table
@ECHO  ^<div class=^"div-table-row^"^>%%j^</div^> >> %~dp0%computername%.html

rem | Write mac address
@ECHO ^<div class=^"div-table-row^"^>^<div class=^"div-table-cell-third^"^>MAC Address^</div^>^<div class=^"div-table-cell^"^>%%i^</div^>^</div^> >> %~dp0%computername%.html

rem | Filter connection by mac address and for each write ip address, mask ans gateway
@FOR /F "skip=2 delims=,{} tokens=2,3,4" %%a IN ('wmic nicconfig where ^(ipenabled^="true" AND macaddress^="%%i"^) get DefaultIPGateway^, IPAddress^, IPSubnet /format:csv') DO (
@ECHO ^<div class=^"div-table-row^"^>^<div class=^"div-table-cell-third^"^>IP Address^</div^>^<div class=^"div-table-cell^"^>%%b^</div^>^</div^> >> %~dp0%computername%.html
@ECHO ^<div class=^"div-table-row^"^>^<div class=^"div-table-cell-third^"^>Subnet^</div^> ^<div class=^"div-table-cell^"^>%%c^</div^>^</div^> >> %~dp0%computername%.html
@ECHO ^<div class=^"div-table-row^"^>^<div class=^"div-table-cell-third^"^>Gateway^</div^> ^<div class=^"div-table-cell^"^>%%a^</div^>^</div^> >> %~dp0%computername%.html
)
)

rem Close table DIV
@ECHO ^</div^> >> %~dp0%computername%.html

rem Close Main DIV
@ECHO ^</div^> >> %~dp0%computername%.html

pause
```

It works just fine, but tho only problem is IPv6 address and 64 after subnet mask (I marked it with red lines on screenshot)
[image]
The only way to get rid of those in output which I fugured out is to create two more cycle which will will take %%b and %%c as input and using ; as delimiter output only IPv4 address.
But I fail to write proper code, because I can not properly escape characters. So, here I am, asking for help.
Here is part of code which I change in attempt to get rid of IPv6 address

```
rem | Gather info on connections
rem | Get Connection name and its mac address
@FOR /F "skip=2 delims=, tokens=2,3" %%i IN ('wmic nic where PhysicalAdapter^=true get MACAddress^, NetConnectionID /format:csv') DO (

rem | Write Connection name as table row, as header of table
@ECHO  ^<div class=^"div-table-row^"^>%%j^</div^> >> %~dp0%computername%.html

rem | Write mac address
@ECHO ^<div class=^"div-table-row^"^>^<div class=^"div-table-cell-third^"^>MAC Address^</div^>^<div class=^"div-table-cell^"^>%%i^</div^>^</div^> >> %~dp0%computername%.html

rem | Filter connection by mac address and for each write ip address, mask ans gateway
@FOR /F "skip=2 delims=,{} tokens=2,3,4" %%a IN ('wmic nicconfig where ^(ipenabled^="true" AND macaddress^="%%i"^) get DefaultIPGateway^, IPAddress^, IPSubnet /format:csv') DO (

rem | Get rid of IPv6 address 
@FOR /F "delims=; tokens=1" %%z IN (%%b) DO (
@ECHO ^<div class=^"div-table-row^"^>^<div class=^"div-table-cell-third^"^>IP Address^</div^>^<div class=^"div-table-cell^"^>%%b^</div^>^</div^> >> %~dp0%computername%.html
)

@ECHO ^<div class=^"div-table-row^"^>^<div class=^"div-table-cell-third^"^>Subnet^</div^> ^<div class=^"div-table-cell^"^>%%c^</div^>^</div^> >> %~dp0%computername%.html
@ECHO ^<div class=^"div-table-row^"^>^<div class=^"div-table-cell-third^"^>Gateway^</div^> ^<div class=^"div-table-cell^"^>%%a^</div^>^</div^> >> %~dp0%computername%.html
)
)
```

But it reports that "Can not find file" using as filename token with IPv4 address, as shown at picture below.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

OK, O fugured it out.
I just need to escape double quotes around %%b and %%c in inner cycle. So, final code should look like:

```
rem | Gather info on connections
rem | Get Connection name and its mac address
@FOR /F "skip=2 delims=, tokens=2,3" %%i IN ('wmic nic where PhysicalAdapter^=true get MACAddress^, NetConnectionID /format:csv') DO (

rem | Write Connection name as table row, as header of table
@ECHO  ^<div class=^"div-table-row^"^>%%j^</div^> >> %~dp0%computername%.html

rem | Write mac address
@ECHO ^<div class=^"div-table-row^"^>^<div class=^"div-table-cell-third^"^>MAC Address^</div^>^<div class=^"div-table-cell^"^>%%i^</div^>^</div^> >> %~dp0%computername%.html

rem | Filter connection by mac address and for each write ip address, mask ans gateway
@FOR /F "skip=2 delims=,{} tokens=2,3,4" %%a IN ('wmic nicconfig where ^(ipenabled^="true" AND macaddress^="%%i"^) get DefaultIPGateway^, IPAddress^, IPSubnet /format:csv') DO (

rem | Get rid of IPv6 address 
@FOR /F "delims=; tokens=1" %%z IN (^"%%b^") DO (
@ECHO ^<div class=^"div-table-row^"^>^<div class=^"div-table-cell-third^"^>IP Address^</div^>^<div class=^"div-table-cell^"^>%%z^</div^>^</div^> >> %~dp0%computername%.html
)

rem | Get rid of bitmask
@FOR /F "delims=; tokens=1" %%y IN (^"%%c^") DO (
@ECHO ^<div class=^"div-table-row^"^>^<div class=^"div-table-cell-third^"^>Subnet^</div^> ^<div class=^"div-table-cell^"^>%%y^</div^>^</div^> >> %~dp0%computername%.html
)

@ECHO ^<div class=^"div-table-row^"^>^<div class=^"div-table-cell-third^"^>Gateway^</div^> ^<div class=^"div-table-cell^"^>%%a^</div^>^</div^> >> %~dp0%computername%.html
)
)

pause
```

And produce output without IPv6 and without 64 bitmask.
Cheers ;-)

Comment: `... in ("string") ...` uses the literal string (not as a filename). To change that behavior, use `usebackq` (see `for /?`)

Comment: Escaping the quotes does not change anything, `for /F … in (^"string^") do …` is quite the same as `… in ("string") do …`; the thing is whether quotes are present at all…